# Where can I put Grails test common classes for all types of tests

Tags: grails

I would like to have some common helper classes for unit and integration tests.

Where to put them? Is there any convention?

The common helper test classes should not be located in production code.

Answer (score 0):

You could put thoses classes in the `src/groovy` (or `java`) directory of a dedicated Grails plugin. Then you put a test dependency to this plugin in your main project and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You could put common or helper classes in the src/groovy directory  if it is a .groovy or src/java  directory if it is a .java

And you can write your actual test classes under test/unit or test/integration directory